# Jenkins running a job if 2 jobs in 2 different pipelines are successfull

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jobs, pipeline

i have 2 pipelines in jenkins and i need to run a final job if last 2 jobs in 2 pipelines are successfull.

job 1 ( which will build periodically at 7PM ) will call 2 jobs job_pipeline1_1 and job_pipeline2_1.

- job1

  - job_pipeline1_1 -- job_pipeline1_2
  - job_pipeline2_1 -- job_pipeline2_2

    - job_final (should be called only after job_pipeline1_2, job_pipeline2_2 are successfull)

job_pipeline1_1 and job_pipeline1_2 are independent of job_pipeline2_1 and job_pipeline2_2 and will run on differnt servers.

job_final should be called only if job_pipeline1_2 and job_pipeline2_2 are successfull in that particular build.

job_final should be in the pipeline.

check this image  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Upc.png"

Can any one help me in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins plugin "Build Flow Plugin" to run your jobs in parallel. 
In that case your final job will be executed after completion of parallel jobs.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, Thanks the solution. but i have to run the last job first. In my case first will be started first. and it calls the other two jobs, in which some process is going on job by job.

Comment: create job1

within job_final you'll have to check did pipeline jobs finished successfully. job_final will be executed two times.

Comment: create jobs: job1,job_pipeline1_1,1_2,2_1,2_2,job_final
and set post build action for job1 to "Build other projects: job_pipeline1_1,job_pipeline2_1"
within post build actions for each 1_1,2_1 add step "Build other projects: job_pipeline*_2"
Within each job *_2 add "Build other job: job_final".

within job_final you just check did both pipeline jobs finished successfully. 
PS: keep in mind that job_final will be executed two times.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ruben, and is there any way to execute job_final  job only once?